# Windows 10 mouse no longer working

Tags: usb

Suddenly my mouse stopped working on Windows 10. I tried two different mice separately and neither works. I tested both of these mice on another windows machine and they worked flawlessly.

I also tried running a live disk from USB to check if it might be hardware related and when trying to boot the Linux Live, it hangs.

Does anyone have any idea what this might be? My fear is that it's hardware related to the USB ports, but I want to know if there are any ways to find out definitely.

Comment: Do other USB devices work OK (like a flash drive)?  If you reboot Windows into Safe Mode, does the USB behave any differently?  Anything related reported in Windows' Event Log?   Anything reporting as failed in the Device Manager?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware failure.  Have you tried a USB port connected to one your machines other USB Hubs?  If you don't know how many Hubs your machine has, open it up, and trace the cable connections.

Comment: Some Linux Live will hangs if it is not compatible with your computer, try ubuntu, by this way you can check if this is hardware issue

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 yes, when I unplug and replug I get an error 43, something about device descriptor failed

Comment: @Bilo the USB had Ubuntu on it, it just randomly hangs during loading of the files. Very randomly will stop.

Comment: @LucasKauffman If there is USB hardware issue on your computer then you boot the ubuntu via USB, it might hang for sure. Can you boot from Live CD? Besides, except mouse, does keyboard is working? If keyboard is working, can you go to Device Manager to check if there is any driver issue?